# Rspec custom matcher for Date Format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, datetime, rspec

I've created a Rspec custom matcher for the format to which a date_of_birth attribute gets saved in the database. This attribute is saved in the database in the format:

```
"Fri, 12 Oct 1990 00:00:00 SAST +02:00"
```

My custom matcher is as follows:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_a_full_datetime do |expected|
  match do |datetime|
    datetime =~ /\w{3} \d+, \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}/
  end
end
```

My question is, what is the format of the Regex that checks that the format is of the format:

```
Fri, 12 Oct 1990 00:00:00 SAST +02:00
```

Because my current Regex is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
/\w{3}, \d{2} \w{3} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \w{4} [-+]?\d{2}:\d{2}/
```